# setTitleColor not working on backpress inside drawerlayout android studio

Tags: android, titlebar

i have tried following code inside fragment

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FF6800\">" + Titles.home + "</font>")));
```

Comment: How do you set the color?

Comment: setting it using above and also used         (getActivity()).setTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#e84a5f"));

Comment: when i am comming back it is setting white color i dont know from where it is taking white color

Answer (score 0):

Try this in onResume

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Comment: you need to .replace R.color.white with your color code :)

Comment: yes i have done this but it don't work when we come back from other fragments as i am using navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFF6800);
```

in your activity and call it from your fragment